# Extract data from array and store as json

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to convert array of json objects into single json object.

```
  const source = [ [{"id":"20210728","item":"Item 1","description":"Details of Item1"},{"id":"20210729","item":"Item 2","description":"Details of Item2"}],[{"id":"20210717","item":"Item 3","description":"Details of Item3"}] ]
```

I need this to be converted as

```
 const destination =   [{"id":"20210728","item":"Item 1","description":"Details of Item1"},{"id":"20210728","item":"Item 2","description":"Details of Item2"},{"id":"20210717","item":"Item 3","description":"Details of Item3"}]
```

Could someone help please? I am a learner of React JS. Please accept my ignorance if it is a silly question.
Thanks,
Sasi

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: You want to "flatten" `source`, hence -> [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)